# User login status using sessions in ONE inc_ file

Tags: php, mysql, session

I'm trying to create a php include file to add to all of my pages, so I can hide certain page information from users who are not logged in.

I hope I have commented enough of the code to make it clear what I am planning..

Is this the best way to try and keep all this in one file rather that making 4 or 5 other files to handle the login status of the user?

All input are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
php session_start(); 

// $layout is the top half of a div that will contain the login status bar (the closing tag is at the bottom of this include file.
$layout='
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;      
        margin:0px;
    }
    .loginbar {
        font-size: 12px;
        text-align: right;
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-right: 25px;
        height: 35px;
        width: 100%;
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #404040;
    }
    </style>
    <div class="loginbar">';

if ($_GET['logout']=='yes'){ // Has the user clicked the log out link?

    start_session();
    destroy_session();

} else { // No, so carry on..

        if !isset($_SESSION['lastname']){ //Is a session already running?

            if(!empty($_POST['user']) || !empty($_POST['pass'])) {
                #READ $_POST and check $_POST['username'] && $_POST['password'] against the database entries and get the respective 'FirstName' and 'LastName' of the user.
                # Set Session vars

                } else (empty($_POST['user']) || empty($_POST['pass'])) {
                echo $layout;
                # DISPLAY LOGIN FORM -> form will resend to this page
                }

        } else {
            echo $layout;
            echo "WELCOME ".$FirstName." ".$LastName;
            #display LOG OUT link. -> Link will send $_GET['logut='yes'] back to this page.
        }
}
?>
</div>

<?php /*
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//In any pages that this inc file is used, I will attempt to block certain bits of information like this:

<?php if ($_SESSION["lastname"]){ ?>
<p style="color:#ff0000;">This is some text that you should only be able to read if you have logged in.</p>
<?php } ?> 

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
*/
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicaly, your workflow is okay.
First I would suggest to make sure you verify all user input before using it further. 
Second, keeping parts of layout into a variable could cause you problems, when the design needs to change. Having organized template files for anything like this would be better and will save you a lot of time in the future.

Next, like you have the code here, you seem to be forced to dump html into your pages. If you only want to check the login status, than I think you should try and clean more of the output intructions you have here, leaving them into the php files that would include this one.

So, for something more complex you will not be able to completely separate the login logic into a single file and include that without trade-offs.

I hope I understood your question, and I'm not offtopic :)

Comment: I think I understand where you're going with that. The site this is going on is not that complex, hence why I wanted this include, just to hide a few things. Thanks :)